# Matlab: Using calculating with days.

Tags: matlab

My problem is the following:

I have a start day. For example: 30 - Oct - 2010

And I know how many business days I need to count back. For example: 250 business days.

Now I want to be able to calculate the start date.

Start date = (30 - Oct - 2010) - (250 Business Days) - (Amount of weekends during those 250  days).

But I don't know how to calculate the "amount of weekends".

Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Jonathan

Comment: This question vaguely remembers similar things I did very long time ago. I think I used Julian dates and, knowing a reference date, use modulo(7) for deciding if Monday, Tuesday,... May be you could have a look at http://5dspace-time.org/Calendar/Algorithm.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way in Matlab:

```
% Data:
count_back = 250;
start_day = datenum('31-Oct-2013');

% Computations:
start_weekday = mod(start_day+4,7);
aux = cumsum(mod(start_weekday-1:-1:start_weekday-max(2*count_back,3),7) < 5);
days_back = find(aux==count_back, 1);
solution_date = datestr(start_day - days_back)
```

Comments:

- In the first line of computations, a `0` in `start_weekday` indicates that `start_day` is Mon; `1` indicates that it is Thu etc. The `+4` is needed because the reference date of the `datenum` function is 01-Jan-0000.
- The comparison `<5` in the second line gives `1` for business days and `0` for weekends. The function `cumsum` gives the cumulative sum from yesterday backwards, reaching until `max(2*count_back,3)` days into the past. The number `max(2*count_back,3)` is always enough (it could be adjusted more finely).
- The `1` in the third line is needed because we want the *first* day into the past that gives the desired `count_back`. If that day is Mon, the previous Sun and Sat would also have the desired `count_back`, but we don't want them.